# Finding logic for a different form of an answer.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

> $20$ persons are sitting on a clean round table. Find the number of ways of selecting $4$ persons. Such that no two of them are consecutive.

**My approach**

I selected one out of $20$, and the remaining $3$ should be selected out of $17$ persons (removing the selected one and his adjacents). With at least gap of one person between them. So this is now equivalent to selecting $3$ person in a linear arrangement not adjacent to each other from $17$ persons for which the ways is $^{15}\text{C}_3$.

Multiplying both selection gives, $^{20}\text{C}_1\cdot^{15}\text{C}_3$

But this has repetition four times for each of the first selected person.

So, total cases is $\frac{^{20}\text{C}_1\cdot^{15}\text{C}_3}{4}$

But the text book in which the question was gives answer as $\frac{^{20}\text{C}_1\cdot^{15}\text{C}_3}{4}$ and $^{17}\text{C}_4- ^{15}\text{C}_2$

And has a note that both answers have separate logic. Obviously these are inter convertible and has same value, but I am unable to find a different logic for this one.

Comment: We select 1 person, example person at seat n°10. So n°9 and n°11 are forbidden for the rest of the process. If person n°2 is seat n°12, impact for 3rd person is not the same as if personn°2is at seat n°13.  If the 2 first persons selected are n°10 and n°12, only n°9, n°11 and n°13 are forbidden for te following steps.  n°11 is duplicated.   Another way to see this is to select 10 persons, with same constraint. With your method, you find $0$ possibility ; in reality, there are $2$ possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic for the second formula is:

- Firstly seat in a straight line. Imagine $16$ empty chairs laid out in a line. There will be $17$ interstices (**including two at the ends**) so $4$ non-adjacent chairs can be inserted into the line in $\binom{17}4$ ways
- But this includes an arrangement in which two of the four chairs are at the extremities (so would become adjacent if rolled into a circle). So now do a similar straight line  exercise with $2$ chairs to be inserted in $16$ empty chairs using only the $15$ **interior interstices** in $\binom{15}2$ ways, and subtract